# Carousel angular-ui change to controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello i follow tutorial from angular-ui [enter link description here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel).
And it worked fine now i want to change it to controller as syntax can some one tell me how to to do it, for this carousel and for the other elements ?

sample code:

```
    app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    that = this;
    that.myInterval = 5000;
    that.noWrapSlides = false;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];


    that.addSlide = function() {
        var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
        slides.push({
            image: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
            text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
            ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
        });
    };
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        that.addSlide();
    }
}]);
```

and in template:

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl as carousel">
    <div style="height: 305px">
        <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in carousel.slides" active="slide.active">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                    <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great.. How it is working for you? what all the scripts you have added/referred ? See my question.. it is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645876/uib-carousel-showing-all-images-at-once-when-i-use-ng-repeat.

Comment: Its working strait from example you need to have angularjs. Than create app next just use controller from example and worked fine. Now I want to convert it to controllerAs syntax

Comment: thanks. Let me try. Do you find anything wrong in my code (Just click on above link). It is not working for me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to use example on page in controller as syntax angularjs. I try a bit but no good results.

Comment: I believe i managed to figure this out. the solution is use that=this; but also include $scope to controller. Some times it breaks when i click to fast but that is just a $watcher....

Comment: @user2217288, thanks. it is working for me as well with test application. something wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

You also appear to be missing `var` from your `that` instantiation.  You need to say `var that = this;` or you're adding it to the global `window` object - almost certainly NOT what you want.  Also, if you're not using `$scope`, don't inject it.

Finally, [we expose](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js#L203) the `UibCarouselController` using `controllerAs` syntax as `carousel` so you may want to pick a different name.

Comment: var yes you so right. I change to carouselCtrl so no conflict here, i need $scope because i use Watch in my controller to change mini slides depends on big slide :) just for  learning purpose.

Comment: You're going to need to post a plunker (and the code) demonstrating where you want to use the controllerAs syntax.